# How to add data binding in old android project while adding new Activity?

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting databinding error while adding activity via Android studio. How to resolve this error ?.

I am trying to add New Activity in my existing project via android studio. That time i used `targetSdkVersion 30` sdk. But after updating `targetSdkVersion 32`, While trying to add New Activity via android studio, getting this error as shown in picture.

This is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
}
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.softwares.bannari.whatstouch"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 32
        versionCode 47
        versionName "1.1.47"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable false
            minifyEnabled true
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    bundle {
        language {
            enableSplit = false
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
//    implementation project(path: ':nativetemplates')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.2.10'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.4.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'

    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    implementation 'the.bot.box:appusagemonitor:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.12.0'
//    implementation project(path: ':nativetemplates')
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0'
    implementation 'com.github.ybq:Android-SpinKit:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.natheeshsunway:Android-Permissions:2.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.17.1'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.github.antonKozyriatskyi:CircularProgressIndicator:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.rm:rmswitch:1.2.2'

    implementation "ru.tinkoff.scrollingpagerindicator:scrollingpagerindicator:1.0.6"
    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:3.5.0"

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.7.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.14.7'
    implementation "androidx.preference:preference:1.2.0"

    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'
    implementation 'com.suddenh4x.ratingdialog:awesome-app-rating:2.2.1'
    implementation 'org.aviran.cookiebar2:cookiebar2:1.1.4'
    implementation 'eu.dkaratzas:android-inapp-update:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.akexorcist:localization:1.2.6'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.7'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.3.5'

    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.4.2'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.4.2'


    def lifecycle_version = "2.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.4.1"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:2.4.1"

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

[image]

Comment: File> Sync Project with gradle files should fix it. Also just delete the import line and reimport the binding if that does not work

Comment: Have you enabled the dataBinding..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First delete the first line (imported library ) for **ActivityGroupsActivityBinding**, don't delete the Binding class and its object. Then click on the **ActivityGroupsActivityBinding** class name then you will got importing suggestion from left side. Or you can import again by clicking on it then pressing **alt+enter**

See how to use [Databinding in Android](https://www.fluttertpoint.com/android-databinding).